# How to write e2e tests for Ledger hardware wallets in Javascript app

Tags: javascript, e2e-testing, cryptocurrency, hardware-wallet, ledger-nano-s

I want to write e2e test for implementation ledger hardware wallet to my app.
I dont have any clue how to mock hardware ledger so it behaves like a real one.

Does anybody do it before?

Comment: it depends if you want to mock u2f or hid. Is it backend or client side?

Comment: @purpletentacle u2f, client-side